# VS Studio 2022 SPA/ASP.NET Project Publish to Folder Doesn't Include React SPA Files While Publish to Azure Does

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a react/asp.net project created with the associated template in Visual Studio 2022. This template includes both the SPA and API sections under one project. When publishing directly to an Azure Web App, both the SPA and API code is built and packaged. When publishing to a folder, which I require for production scenarios, it does not build or include the SPA code.

I have tried both the GUI publish and MSBuild CLI.

This is the associated section in .csproj that works for other publishing methods:

```
<Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build" />

    <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)build\**" />
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
        <RelativePath>wwwroot\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
      </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

the current 'Target' section seems to be specific to publishing to Azure Web Apps, so it may not work for other publishing scenarios.

Please try to add the following code to 'ItemGroup':

```
    <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="$(SpaRoot)public\**" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
        <RelativePath>wwwroot\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
    </ResolvedFileToPublish>
```